# $E/L$, $L/K$ normal then $E/K$ normal

Tags: solution-verification, normal-extension

I have to decide if the following statement is true:

> If $E/L$, $L/K$ are normal, then $E/K$ is normal

I have though of this proof but I don't know if it is correct, could someone help me?

> Let $p(x) \in K[x]$ and let $\alpha \in E$ be a root of $p(x)$. If $\alpha \in L$ then all the other roots of $p(x)$ are in $L$ (because $L/K$ is normal) and therefore they are also in $E$. Thus $E/K$ is normal. If $\alpha \notin L$ then we can also see $p(x) \in K[x]$ as a polynomial in $L[x]$. If $p(x) \in L[x]$ has a root $\alpha \in E$ then all its other roots are also in $E$ because $E/L$ is normal. Therefore $E/K$ is normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false: Consider $K = \mathbb{Q}$, $L = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, and $E = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{2}]$.

Indeed, in this case we have $E/L$ and $L/K$ are degree 2, and thus automatically Galois extensions. However, $E/K$ is not normal, as $x^4 - 2$ has a root in $E$, but does not split completely.

Comment: First of all, the definition on normality involves the splitting of *irreducible* polynomials. The error in your proof is the following: you seem to use implicitly that an irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in K[x]$ is also irreducible as a polynomial over $L$, but this is false.